# jquery select specific id (parrent?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple div's/boxes in my code, and want to animate only the div when I clicked the button in that specific div. Each div has another ID, the ID will be get from the database, users can submit new data to the database and a new div with a new ID will be generated automatically. ID's are called like "#1", "#2" etc. the number of the ID get from the database. How to select with jquery the specific div ID by clicking the button inside that div? We are not using click events, we are using a ScriptManager and UpdatePanel. Our jquery code looks like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_beginRequest(function (source, args) {
                $("the id of the div here, how to get the right id?").fadeOut(2000);
            });

            prm.add_endRequest(function (source, args) {
                // any other code you want to execute after the post back finishes


                window.location.href = "campagnes.aspx";
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: What do I need to look after at source?

Comment: _when I clicked the button in that specific div._ you didn't include it.

Comment: Include it? How do you mean?

Comment: i mean't you have not posted that code in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this fiddle,
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hquj4uoe/)

Please refer to this code to get an idea

```
<style>
.divstyle
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
<script>

function animatediv(ctrl)
{
    debugger
    $("#"+ctrl.parentNode.id).fadeOut(2000);
}
</script>
<div id="div1" class="divstyle"><input type ="button" onclick="animatediv(this);" value="click"/></div>
<div id="div2" class="divstyle"><input type ="button" onclick="animatediv(this);" value="click"/></div>
<div id="div3" class="divstyle"><input type ="button" onclick="animatediv(this);" value="click"/></div>
<div id="div4" class="divstyle"><input type ="button" onclick="animatediv(this);" value="click"/></div>
<div id="div5" class="divstyle"><input type ="button" onclick="animatediv(this);" value="click"/></div>
```

Comment: yes, that's actually what I want! The first time I tested it it worked.. but now nothing happens, only the page will refresh.

Comment: How to do this before postback happens? It is working but because of my ASP postback the page will refresh so you can't see the fadeout anymore...

Comment: @Brian98 try commenting this line, window.location.href = "campagnes.aspx"; I think this might be causing the page refresh.

Comment: No my page refresh is caused by the postback of the ASP page because my button contains an CommandName and CommandArgument to update data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery, you can use this:

```
$('div').click(function(e) { $(e.currentTarget).fadeOut(2000); });
```

In Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager I think you can access to element object from args.

```
$(args.get_postBackElement()).fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: Last one isn't working at all, no error message, nothing happens, it will update the database and refresh the page..

Comment: I get it from documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397432%28v=vs.100%29.aspx I am not see button in your code.